# Deleting a line in a list by seleting one point "connected" to it in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list of "points/dots" and a list of lines. I want to delete all the lines connected to a point when I delete that same point.

Until now, I've tried the following:

```
            foreach (Line g in lines)
                lines.Remove(g.lineContainsPoint(g, selectionPoint));
```

The method lineContainsPoint:

```
    public bool lineContainsPoint(Line s, Point c)
    {
        if (s.Source == c || s.Destination == c)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

The error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation
>   may not execute.

Comment: Because you are using a foreach loop, you can't remove something from what you are currently iterating around. If you build up a collection of lines that need to be removed and then, outside of the foreach loop you remove them it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify a collection inside a **foreach** loop*. You can either filter the lines you want to remove and then remove them from the lines list:

```
var linesToRemove = lines.Where(g => g.lineContainsPoint(g, selectionPoint)).ToArray();

foreach (Line line in linesToRemove)
                lines.Remove(line);
```

Or, iterate over the list with a bare index instead of a foreach:

```
var i = 0;
while(i < lines.Count) {
   if (lines[i].lineContainsPoint(g, selectionPoint))
      lines.RemoveAt(i);
   else
      i++;
}
```

- Being more specific, you're not allowed to modify a collection while enumerating it through an `IEnumerable` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete entries from a list which you are currently iterating. What you can do is create a new list, in which you only insert those entries which you want to keep (e.g. all entries that you want removed will not be inserted in the new list).